# Java one same name can be occured in combobox

Tags: java, file, combobox

How can I have only one same name in my combobox? There are 2 same name in my fee text file and I want to get the name from fee text file to the combobox. But it display 2 same name.

There are no error in my code and I cannot find out the questions. I think my combobox function got problems. Below is my expected result.

```
//fee.txt
john|123|0.00
john|456|0.00

//my expected result in combobox
john

//my result
john
john

//filefuncion.java
public class FileFunction {

public static ArrayList getContent(File f) {
    ArrayList ls = null;
    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));) {
        String line;
        ls = new ArrayList();
        /*while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            ls.add(line);
        }*/
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.trim().length() > 0) {
            ls.add(line);
        }
  }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ls;
 }

//my code   
private void combobox(){
    File file = new File("fee.txt");
    ArrayList al = FileFunction.getContent(file);
    for (Object obj : al) {
        String newobj = obj.toString();
        String text[] = newobj.split("\\|");
        String name = text[0];
        String status = text[2];
        if(status.equals("0.00")){
            comboboxResident.addItem(name);   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Load the values from the text file into a Set

Comment: Is this Swing, AWT, Java-FX..?  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 0):

First, use generics to ensure a stronger type-checking and reduce bugs due to incorrect types. Write something like `ArrayList<String>` instead of plain `ArrayList`.

If you want to remove duplicate elements in an `ArrayList` instance, the most convenient way is to build a `Set` (which is a class under the Collection framework) and convert it back to `ArrayList` (if you need to).

For example, suppose you have an ArrayList instance, then you may write

```
ArrayList<String> list = ...
LinkedHashSet<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<>(list);
```

Just iterate through `set` will do. Or you can convert it back to a list by `ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<>(set);`.

A `LinkedHashSet` implements the `Set` interface and does not contain duplicate elements. It also has predictable iteration order. If you want to further sort you elements, try a `TreeSet` instead.